# Submit flink job to remote virtualbox does not work

Tags: apache-flink

```
package org.myorg.quickstart;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.LocalFlinkMiniCluster;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;

public class WordCount {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final LocalFlinkMiniCluster cluster = new LocalFlinkMiniCluster(new Configuration(), false); //line 16
    cluster.start(); //line 17

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("localhost", 6123);

    final long N = 10;
    DataStream<Long> stream = env.generateSequence(1, N);
    stream.map(new MapFunction<Long, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long map(Long value) throws Exception {
            return 2 * value;
        }
    }).print();
    env.execute("WC Test");
}

public static final class LineSplitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

    @Override
    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
        // normalize and split the line
        String[] tokens = value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");

        // emit the pairs
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.length() > 0) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(token, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Above code can run locally (windows + IDEA) successfully on local mini-cluster.

Then, I comment out Line 16 and 17. I start a `Flink` in virtualbox either by `start-local.sh` or `start-cluster.sh`. However, my program is failed in `IDEA` this time. It complained about the unconnected to job manager as follows.

Can anyone help me find out why it is failed? Do I need special setting for `Flink` in virtualbox. I already forward the `JobManager` port `6123` in virtualbox setting. I even compile the `jar` and run the `jar` inside of the virtualbox with same error.

```
09:16:00,631 INFO org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment - Running remotely at localhost:6123
09:16:01,220 INFO org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient - Submitting job with JobID: 2e53f2e2f66f023c2f4748f7fe6d4545. Waiting for job completion.
Submitting job with JobID: 2e53f2e2f66f023c2f4748f7fe6d4545. Waiting for job completion.
09:16:01,220 INFO org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient - Starting client actor system.
09:16:02,212 INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
09:16:02,295 INFO Remoting - Starting remoting
09:16:02,530 INFO Remoting - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:56050]
09:16:02,542 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor - Disconnect from JobManager null.
09:16:02,550 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor - Received job Window WordCount (2e53f2e2f66f023c2f4748f7fe6d4545).
09:16:02,550 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor - Could not submit job Window WordCount (2e53f2e2f66f023c2f4748f7fe6d4545), because there is no connection to a JobManager.
09:16:02,624 WARN akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:6123]].

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try to set `jobmanager.rpc.address` to `0.0.0.0` because by default it [set to `localhost`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/setup/config.html#jobmanager-amp-taskmanager). So, seems like the Job Manager accept connections from `localhost/127.0.0.1` only by default.

Comment: Yet one question: what IP do you see in Flink Web UI by path `Job Manager/Configuration/jobmanager.rpc.address`?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the issue is because the code lib from maven is different with flink running version. Once I make sure all lib are updated to flink 1.1.2, there is no issues.